# Flexbox: How to make an element stick to the right end of its container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My intention was to have one big square and inside it two small squares.

One square (small-left) is supposed to stick to the left end of the big square, and the other(small-right) is supposed to stick to the right end.

This is what I get:

[image]

Do you know what can make the right-small square stick to the right?

Please look at the code I wrote:

```css
.big {
  display: flex;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border: solid;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.small-right,
.small-left {
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  border: solid;
}

.small-right {
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="small-left"></div>
  <div class="small-right"></div>
</div>
```

You can also see the code in Code-Pen: https://codepen.io/CrazySynthax/pen/OmMxQw

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have many options. Here are three:

- add `justify-content: space-between` to the flex container, OR
- add `margin-right: auto` to the first flex item, OR
- add `margin-left: auto` to the second flex item.

Here's an explanation of how each property works:

- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items along the Main Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Answer (score 5):

You can use margin:

```css
.big {
  display: flex;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border: solid;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.small-right,
.small-left {
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  border: solid;
}

.small-right {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
  <div class="small-left"></div>
  <div class="small-right"></div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zwrEXo

Comment: I was trying to make a responsive form with the <input>s sliding below the label but staying flush to the right.  
I came up with the following solution (based on this answer by @G-Cyr):  
https://codepen.io/JuanLanus/pen/NWWmmgm

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

Add **justify-content: space-between**  to the main div.**Remove-- margin-top: auto;** from small-right class.

```
 <div class="big">
         <div class="small-left"></div>
         <div class="small-right"></div>
     </div>



   .big {
      display: flex;
      width: 40vw;
      height: 10vw;
      border: solid;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .small-right,
    .small-left {
      width: 5vw;
      height: 5vw;
      border: solid;
    }
```